# Why did Protagonist want Kat to do the exchange?

Tags: tenet

> Protagonist: **Your wife does the exchange**.
>
> Sator: I never involve her in my business.
>
> Protagonist: Yeah, that's why I trust her.

Why did Protagonist even need Kat to do the exchange? Why can't he do it himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He wants to make sure she is not killed. Kat is not supposed to replace Protagonist in the exchange; she is supposed to receive the package from him.